# Why am I getting this error while installing Sencha Cmd on linux: Failed to execute default file manager

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

I'm trying to install latest Sencha Cmd on linux and it is failing.

Failed to execute default file manager.

I would think an install would be the easy part?

Answer (score 0):

Sencha Cmd is not supported by all Linux versions so maybe you have an older version. Try upgrading or installing on Windows

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this:

file SenchaCmd-4.0.2.67-linux-x64.run.zip
SenchaCmd-4.0.2.67-linux-x64.run.zip
mkdir ala
cd ala
unzip ../SenchaCmd-4.0.2.67-linux-x64.run.zip
chmod +x SenchaCmd-4.0.2.67-linux-x64.run
./SenchaCmd-4.0.2.67-linux-x64.run